# Windows Installer Issue: Files Not Replaced After Major Upgrade - Seeking Assistance and Clarification

Tags: windows-installer, wixsharp

This is an installer issue.

Command line: xxx.exe /quiet /norestart

I have a total of 5 machines, with only 1 of them experiencing the issue. The bootstrapper contains 1 MSI, and set ReinstallMode to "amus". After performing a major upgrade, none of the files are being replaced by the new ones, and the old files are not being removed.

Here are some logs:
MSI (s) (8A:E4) [03:01:04:950]: Doing action: MigrateFeatureStates
Action ended 3:01:04: CostFinalize. Return value 1.

MSI (s) (8A:E4) [03:01:04:951]: Migrating feature settings from product(s) '{12345678-E1B8-1119-6CC1-4D1B5811208C}'

MSI (s) (8A:E4) [03:01:04:954]: MigrateFeatureStates: based on existing product, setting feature 'Complete' to 'Advertise' state.

Action start 3:01:04: MigrateFeatureStates.

MSI (s) (8A:E4) [03:01:04:957]: Doing action: InstallValidate
Action ended 3:01:04: MigrateFeatureStates. Return value 1.

MSI (s) (8A:E4) [03:01:04:958]: Feature: Complete; Installed: Absent;   Request: Advertise;   Action: Advertise

MSI (s) (8A:E4) [03:01:04:958]: Component: Component.Agent.exe_111111234; Installed: Absent;   Request: Null;   Action: Null

MSI (s) (8A:E4) [03:01:04:958]: Component: Component.Agent.exe.config_222251410; Installed: Absent;   Request: Null;   Action: Null

MSI (s) (8A:E4) [03:01:04:958]: Component: Component.AgentCache.exe_3333785929; Installed: Absent;   Request: Null;   Action: Null
...

I suspect the root cause may be due to the feature being set to an advertised state, potentially preventing file replacement. (Upon comparing with logs from successful installations, the feature state is set to Local as follows,
"MigrateFeatureStates: based on existing product, setting feature 'Complete' to 'Local' state.

MSI (s) (E4:0C) [03:05:24:948]: Component: Component.Agent.exe_111151234; Installed: Absent;   Request: Local;   Action: Local

MSI (s) (E4:0C) [03:05:24:948]: Component: Component.Agent.exe.config_222251410; Installed: Absent;   Request: Local;   Action: Local

MSI (s) (E4:0C) [03:05:24:948]: Component: Component.AgentCache.exe_1333385929; Installed: Absent;   Request: Local;   Action: Local")

However, I'm uncertain if my assumption is correct. If so, why the feature was set to Advertise state on this machine, I do not add any code for this in my WixSharp code.
Could someone help on this?